# Creating a loop that prints in column of names

Tags: java

The array kids is an array of type Infant that has already been declared and initialized with Infant objects. Write a loop that prints, in a column, the names of the all of the infants in the kids array.

This is the Infant class..

```
public class Infant{

  private  String name;
  private int age;  // in months

  public Infant(String who, int months){
    name = who;
    age = months;
  }

  public String getName(){return name;}

  public int getAge(){return age;}

  public void anotherMonth(){age = age + 1;}
}
```

The code i have tried is

```
for (int j = 0; j<kids.length; j++) {

System.out.println(kids.getName());

}
```

Answer (score 9):

Change your print line statement

```
System.out.println(kids[j].getName());
```

Answer (score 1):

On a side note , another neater way to write the for loop is :

```
 for (Infant i: kids){

          System.out.println(i.getName());
 }
```

Which just boils down to, for all infants in the array kids, do a particular operation( in this case print their names)